# Logstash 2.3.x plugin update issue

Tags: logstash

I tried to download both logstash 2.3.4 and 2.3.3-all .deb, but when i try to run

```
sudo /opt/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin update logstash-patterns-core
```

or any other plugin i get

`WARNING: SSLSocket#session= is not supported
No plugin updated`

also when i try to install `logstash-patterns-core`, it suppose to add some files to `/opt/logstash/patterns`, but it doesn't, however console says that plugin installed succesfully.